# PHP how to create errors in a custom function?

Tags: php, function

What is the best way to go about errors in custom PHP functions? Such as a argument being of the wrong type.

```
function myFunction($string) {
    if (gettype($string) !== 'string') {
        return 'typeError';
    }

    //Rest of function code
}
```

Comment: Well you need to clarify what sort of error you want to display, a string? returning a boolean? Do you want to log errors in a file?

Comment: Do you want to throw exceptions?

Comment: Here is the link: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: Is there throw expressions just like in JavaScript?

Comment: Yes you can use this to manage your response based on your needs.

Comment: [InvalidArgumentException](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.invalidargumentexception.php) would be the best fit here.

Comment: There's no "best" way. I can think of four sensible ways (assertions, return value out of data domain, `trigger_error()` or `throw`). Which one to use depends on your needs, something we can't tell. You may want to add some context so we can provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Just throw an Exception

```
function myFunction($string) {
    if (gettype($string) !== 'string') {
        throw new Exception('typeError');
    }

    //Rest of function code
}
```

You can setup a global exception handler using set_exception_handler, that will output your errors in your preferred way: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php

```
function exception_handler($exception) {
    echo json_encode(['error' => "Uncaught exception: " . $exception->getMessage());
}

set_exception_handler('exception_handler');
```

Comment: You don't need a custom exception handler to print exceptions, PHP will gladly do it for you. In fact a custom exception handler can easily hide errors if you aren't careful.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, yeah you're right. I've updated the answer to show json formatted output since thats what majority apps use it for